# License Screen About Phone - Legal Information - Open Licenses Screen

Tags: android, licensing, android-alertdialog

Trying to find the source code to the Open licenses AlertDialog screen (at least it looks like AlertDialog).  I want to put something similar in it but can't seem t find it.  Does anyone know where to download that source code or have a similar example they can show me?

[image: Open License screen on Droid X2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Settings app is where this is done. See this activity:
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/SettingsLicenseActivity.java
The content itself is generated during the build.